# Populating/Amending the Options of a "PICK LIST" column type in Smartsheet

Tags: javascript, json, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am contemplating using the Smartsheet API to address some of the background activities I need to happen on the sheets that I have access to. I am not committed to any specific Code/language at this stage but have been trying to get my head round json and JavaScript.

I see that using the GET Sheets allows me to see the details of sheets and I can see the options in a Pick list.  I have also see code that would allow me to amend an existing entry in a row by changing the option selected.

What I want to be able to do is to run a code and updates the Row Items of the Pick list.  Any suggestions/guidance would be very welcome.  Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the list of choices available for each cell within a `PICKLIST` column by issuing an **Update Column** request and supplying the picklist choices in the `options` property of the request. For example:

```
PUT /sheets/{sheetId}/columns/{columnId}
{
    "title":"First Column",
    "index":0, 
    "type" : "PICKLIST", 
    "options" :["One","Two"]
}
```

The **Update Column** operation is described here in the docs: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#update-column.

Comment: Kim, much appreciated.  Will give it a go. Do not know how I missed it! Now I know it is possible I can now focus on learning the techniques and best practice to implement it.

Comment: Happy to help, James. If this info sufficiently addressed your question, can you please mark it as an "Accepted" answer?  (Doing so makes others more likely to benefit from this info in the future.) Thanks!

Comment: It is important to note that when updating the `PICKLIST` with new values that you will need to include the current values that are in the `PICKLIST` or they will be removed. For example, if you wanted to add `"Three"` to the above `PICKLIST` your `options` attribute would need to have a value of `["One", "Two", "Three"]` Providing `["Three"]` would update the `PICKLIST` to only have one option.

Comment: @daveSkull81 - Many thanks for the additional comments. my plan is to have a master list in either a different smartsheet or a google sheet and then whenever we require to update the Smartsheet dropdown to run some code to repopulate the dropdown..  Early days as yet.