# Updating Smartsheet Summary Field Pick List values

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

I am currently updating column pick list values in sheets with an API call to keep the options in sync with the source.

There is now a need to apply those same pick list values to a summary field pick list options list.

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974171/populating-amending-the-options-of-a-pick-list-column-type-in-smartsheet) confirms how I update a sheet column, which I am doing successfully

However, looking for same keywords and adding 'summary' results in nothing.
Has anyone been able to do this?

I am successfully pulling the summary field values
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets//summary/fields -H "Authorization: Bearer "

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding/Updating summary fields by curl or by the SDK works, refer to the documentation : https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#add-summary-fields